# How to Override logWorkspaceId in Azure CAF Enterprise Scale Module with Archetype Override?

Tags: azure, terraform, azurecaf

I am working with the Azure Cloud Adoption Framework (CAF) for Terraform and facing a challenge in overriding the default value of `logWorkspaceId` in the Enterprise Scale module. My objective is to set a custom value for `logWorkspaceId`, but despite my efforts, the default value remains unchanged.

To achieve this, I've attempted an archetype override, specifically targeting the `es_root` archetype, but without success. My understanding is that archetype overrides should allow for such customizations, but I seem to be missing a step or misconfiguring the override.

Using the archetype override mechanism in the module, focusing on the `es_root` archetype. My configuration looks something like this:

```
module "enterprise_scale" {
  source  = "Azure/caf-enterprise-scale/azurerm"
  version = "5.0.3" # change this to your desired version, 

  default_location = ""

  providers = {
    azurerm              = azurerm
    azurerm.connectivity = azurerm
    azurerm.management   = azurerm
  }

  root_parent_id = data.azurerm_client_config.core.tenant_id
  root_id        = var.root_id
  root_name      = var.root_name
  archetype_config_overrides = {
    root = {
      archetype_id = "es_root"
      parameters = {
        "Deploy-Resource-Diag" = {
         logAnalyticsWorkspaceId = data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example.id
      }
    }
  }
} 

  deploy_core_landing_zones = false
  deploy_management_resources    = true
  subscription_id_management     = local.subscription_id_management
  configure_management_resources = local.configure_management_resources
  
 
}
```

Could someone guide me on how to correctly override the logWorkspaceId parameter in the Azure CAF Enterprise Scale module? Is there a specific method for applying archetype overrides that I might be overlooking, particularly for the es_root archetype?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to provision Override logWorkspaceId in Azure CAF Enterprise Scale Module with Archetype Override and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

To override the `logWorkspaceId` parameter in the Azure Cloud Adoption Framework (CAF) Enterprise Scale module using Terraform, it's important to ensure that the override is correctly specified in the module configuration.

Ensure that the `logAnalyticsWorkspaceId` you want to override is indeed a parameter that can be overridden in the `es_root` archetype. Not all parameters might be overrideable, depending on the module's design.

**My terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demovk-rg"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_management_group" "example" {
  display_name = "Example Management Group"
  name         = "demovk-mg"
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "example" {
  name                = "demovk-workspace"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 30
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "core" {}

module "enterprise_scale" {
  source  = "Azure/caf-enterprise-scale/azurerm"
  version = "5.0.3"

  providers = {
    azurerm              = azurerm
    azurerm.connectivity = azurerm
    azurerm.management   = azurerm
  }

  root_parent_id = data.azurerm_client_config.core.tenant_id
  root_id        = azurerm_management_group.example.name
  root_name      = azurerm_management_group.example.display_name

  default_location = azurerm_resource_group.example.location

  archetype_config_overrides = {
    root = {
      archetype_id = "es_root"
      parameters = {
        "Deploy-Resource-Diag" = {
         logAnalyticsWorkspaceId = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example.id
        }
      }
    }
  }

  deploy_core_landing_zones        = false
  deploy_management_resources      = true
  subscription_id_management       = data.azurerm_client_config.core.subscription_id
    configure_management_resources   = {
    attribute1 = "value1"
    attribute2 = "value2"
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm using the Azure Cloud Adoption Framework (CAF) Enterprise Scale module with Terraform to deploy management resources, following the custom settings examples provided in  https://github.com/Azure/terraform-azurerm-caf-enterprise-scale/wiki/[Examples]-Deploy-Management-Resources-With-Custom-Settings. While I'm able to create a new Log Analytics workspace, I'm encountering an issue where the diagnostic setting is not linking with the newly created workspace. Instead, it defaults to the linked subscription 000000-00. I want to override this setting to use the newly created workspace.

Comment: I see that Policies are getting created in Azure Portal but not creating diagnostic setting as it is failing there